# How to use the security settings for person account?

Tags: security, person-accounts

Is there any option to view the sharring setting of the person account?I  dont find that option any where..

Comment: it is the same account object sharing the person account shares. one more addition is the contact and person account are contacts synonymously...

Answer (score 1):

Person accounts use the sharing setting for accounts.  When you enable person accounts the sharing setting for contacts is changed to controlled by parent, so the only way to change the sharing is through the accounts setting.